# Не могу скачать файл

Tags: windows

https://vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fuhf.su%2FXenoHack%2FXenosDownloader.exe&cc_key=
Вышел ссылка на файл.
Компьютер скачивает файл и сразу же удаляет его.
Помню у меня была такая проблема со Skype.
Решил я ее так.
Скачал на телефон skype и перекинул на компьютер.
Как можно решить проблемму?

Comment: https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/16515b9bd2144a6117f72176f752caf00fb1f349f073920dfab09cf9ee75e696/analysis/1515283816/

Comment: Можно нескромный вопрос? Что по обещаниям должна делать прога?

Comment: @donRumata, ну по названию же гуглится: https://vk.com/topic-120934390_34417025 - и даже ссылка совпадает с той, по которой он скачивает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, протупил, да.

Answer (score 0):

По описанию проблемы ясно, что файл удаляется антивирусом, либо защитой браузера (некоторые браузеры содержат )

[Весьма вероятно](https://www.virustotal.com/ru/file/16515b9bd2144a6117f72176f752caf00fb1f349f073920dfab09cf9ee75e696/analysis/1515283816/), что скачиваемый файл содержит в себе нечто зловредное, впрочем, для читов в этом нельзя быть уверенным.

Если ты уверен в отсутствии зловредов в файле, поступи как написано [в инструкции, по которой ты скачиваешь этот файл](https://vk.com/topic-120934390_34417025) и отключи антивирус и/или защиту браузера. Либо найди файл в карантине и добавь в исключения.

PS: Ссылка на файл:

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent(
"https://vk.com/away.php?to=https%3A%2F%2Fuhf.su%2FXenoHack%2FXenosDownloader.exe&cc_key="
.match(/to=([^&]+)/)[1]
))
```

Comment: Спасибо проблема была в антивирусе.

Comment: Прими ответ нажатием на галочку?